# Detect manually unregistered serviceworkers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, notifications, web-push

I am currently storing all of the users endpoint inside a database table, but I can't figure out how to detect if a user unregisters a service worker manually from the devTools without calling a function I created; `Unsubscribe()`

```js
function Unsubscribe() {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
    reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(sub) {
      sub.unsubscribe().then(function(Success) {
        if (Success)
          fetch('api/push/Unregister', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(sub)
          });
      })

    })
  })
```

[image]